# Unable to use js script from asp.net control textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, datepicker

This is my javascript code for a datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  new datepickr("datepick1", {
 'dateFormat': 'm/d/y'
 });

</script>
```

This works fine for an html textbox like:

```
 <input id="datepick1">
```

But does not work with an asp.net control like:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="datepick1" name="datepick1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please help! I am new to asp.net. So not well versed with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />
```

or

```
  $(function() {
        $('#date').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });

    });    

  <asp:TextBox ID="date" class="field" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Thank You!
I solved it by adding the ClientIdMode="Static" property to the asp.net control.